# India to Jamaica via UK and USA: do I need transit visas?

Tags: usa, uk, transit, indian-citizens

I am going to Jamaica for a medical conference and I have booked my flights via UK and New York. I will stay in JFK, New York airport only two hours and then fly New York to Jamaica.

Do I need visas for USA and UK to catch connecting flights?

Comment: You could get a c visa instead of b1/b2.

Comment: C visa? But where submit my application ?

Comment: Us consult? Or u k consulet

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: This is unclear unless you tell us what citizeship/passport you hold.

Comment: Indian nationality

Answer (score 2):

You will only need a [US C Visa (Transit Visa)](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html) to transit via any US airport.

Regarding the UK, as an Indian citizen you can transit through the UK as long as you're holding a valid US visa.

From the [official gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no):

> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> - **a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)**